# Not been able to get view of followers, instead it's only showing current user as follower of itself

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am building follow relationship in Laravel 5.2, I've defined relationship in User Model and this is my code.

```
public function iamfollowing()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Diskourse\Models\User','followers','user_id','followed_id');
}

public function iamfollowedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Diskourse\Models\User','followers','followed_id','user_id');
}

public function following()
{
    return $this->iamfollowing()->get();
}

public function followers()
{  

 return $this->iamfollowedBy()->get();

}
```

But when I try to display the list of followers it's only displaying current user equals to number of expected followers. This is my view:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-3">

        <!--Followers list-->

            <h4>Followers</h4>

            @if(!$user->followers()->count())

            <p>No followers</p>

            @endif
                @foreach($user->followers() as $follower)

                    @include('user/partials/userblock')

                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That was accidentally when i was writing this problem. Just typing mistake, real problem still remains the same

Comment: Can you change `@if(!$user->followers()->count())` to `@if(!count($user->followers))` and see what happens? also you should include `@foreach($user->followers as $follower)` inside an else of the if condition as if the count of followers is 0 then it doesn't make sense to even use the @foreach

Comment: it's still displaying same. In the database user 1 has two followers so it means that it should display that two users. I tried using dd(), it works fine but when i try to display real view it displays current user two times.